# Swift: Cannot convert of type NSNumber to expected argument type Int16

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a CoreData entity named `EntityOne` and it has two attributes:

`coreValue` of type `Int16`
`coreDate` of type `NSDate`

When I try to access the core data entries from a fetch request and append the values to individual arrays the error appears for the line:
`coreDataValues.append(item.coreValue!)`

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EntityOne")
let fetchResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [EntityOne]

var coreDataDates = [NSDate]()
var coreDataValues = [Int16]()

for item in fetchResults {
                coreDataDates.append(item.coreDate!)
                coreDataValues.append(item.coreValue!)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
item.coreValue!.shortValue
```

You should also think about safely unwrapping these before using them:

```
if let value = item.coreValue {
    coreDataValues.append(value.shortValue)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. When trying this code it changes the error to '' Cannot convert type 'UInt16?' to expected argument type 'Int16' ''

Comment: I've force cast the value as type Int16 and that seems to have solved it. Thanks!

Comment: `Int16` is `value.shortValue`

Comment: Thanks vadian, that is more elegant than typecasting!

Comment: @vadian you're correct, have updated my answer :) misread OP as `UInt16`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!